# how to prove that A/{0} isomorphic to A?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Is there an isomorphism that shows $A/\{0\}$ isomorphic to A?

For me it is intuitively correct as $A/\{0\}$ is just the cosets $a + \{0\}$ for all $a \in A$ which means all $a \in A.$But I do not know the isomorphism that I should write, could someone help me please?

Comment: The isomorphism should just be $\varphi : A \to A /\{0\}$ such that $\varphi(a) = a + \{0\}$. Now it's just a matter of showing $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, that it's injective, and that it's surjective.

Comment: And also, being a homomorphism is just trivial, right?

Comment: Yep.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Emptymind it is, but if you didn't think of this isomorphism yourself, you should explain in detail why it is trivial.

Comment: One nice way of approaching these problems is as follows: if you want to show that $A/B$ is isomorphic to $C$, realize that this is the same as finding a surjective map $\phi: A \to C$ with kernel $B$. Because by the first isomorphism theorem, you know $A/B= A/\ker \phi \cong \text{im } \phi= C$. Can you think of a map $A \to A$ that is surjective and has kernel $\{0 \}$?

Comment: Can I just behave as if the set $\{0\}$ is not there? @TheoBendit

Comment: @Emptymind Yes and no. Yes, the $\{0\}$ is, in practice, essentially not there. No, you shouldn't behave this way in order to prove this isomorphism, because then you're essentially assuming what you're trying to prove. But you are right that the homomorphism property is basically trivial, and if you think about it, so is the surjectivity property. The injectivity property does take a single line of proof though.

Comment: @TheoBendit I think I know how to write the detailed solution now.